# How to handle MapView touch event

Tags: android, android-mapview

How do you handle the touch of a MapView so it allows me to insert a marker by touching a point on the map?

I would also like the coordinates of that point.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an `OnMapClickListener` directly on the `GoogleMap` object.

**For example**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        googleMap = map;

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
            void onMapClick(LatLng point){
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                        point.latitude + ", " + point.longitude,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#add_map_code)

Comment: I gets me off the following error, even if I initialized the object type googleMap..                                                                                                                                                   'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener)' on a null object reference'

Comment: Put the setOnMapClickListener into onMapReady() method